# NodeJS Mysql Leak

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Here is my code. I first used a simple try/catch block as I figured that was the issue, so then I switched to a callback based error handler:

```
var addblockeduser = function(x,y,next) {
    // if error condition?
    if ( y === 0 ) {
        // "throw" the error safely by calling the completion callback
        // with the first argument being the error
        next(new Error("Can't divide by zero"))
    }
    else {
        // no error occured, continue on
        next(null, x/y)

        db.query('SELECT 1', function(err){
                db.end();
        });


    }
}

addblockeduser(10, 0,    function(err, result){
    // did an error occur?
    if ( err ) {
        // handle the error safely
        console.log('4/2=err', err)
    }
    else {
        // no error occured, continue on
        console.log('4/2='+result)
    }
})
```

When I run this, I get the error that is called 'Cannot divide by zero'. **BUT**, when I go and check my MYSQL process list, it shows:

[image]

These random sleep processes that appear each time the code is executed. (If I run the code 20 times 20 new 'sleep' processes will appear) I am even using db.end() to close the connection, and that is still not working, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you never call "db.end()" in case of "y = 0", but only in the "else", maybe that's your problem here ?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply.  Yeah I'm not calling it under that, but how is it still adding a process to my processlist when It's inside the else statement? (It should not be triggering anything after the else statement correct?)

For example, if I add 'console.log('hey');' under the else statement, it is not triggered. But this db.query function is... (and thus is mysql leak) does't make sense?

Comment: I'm just supposing you're already connected to the db, and the "Sleep" is just here for that. You never run the db.query, that's sure, but what if you disconnect to the database in the "if" also ? Maybe the "Sleep" is just here to tell you "A process is connected to the DB and is doing nothing"

Comment: Well, yeah but those sleep processes are accumulative and add up over each request until the wait_timeout threshold is hit, then mysql removes it. So I have to use a higher max_connections variable.  It's just odd how a sleep process would be spawned when that else statement isn't being called hmm